# Select N rows when give n times a same id of a table having id as primary key identity(1,1)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table Drawing with multiple coloumns with ID int PK,Identity(1,1).It has more rows.
when I give same id two times in a single selection ,i nees two rows of same data.but I can't get.

```
`SELECT * FROM DRAWING WHERE ID IN (120,120)`
```

I need the result like following

```
  ID    NAME   Etc.
  120  p001
  120  poo1

 but i can get 1 row only.Plese help me.
```

Comment: give me perfect table structure & data

Comment: This is not possible. If `ID` is the only column in a primary key, it has to have unique values. Also, specifying the same value twice in the `IN` clause won't make a difference for the number of returned records.

Comment: @sureshhh . . . Why do the two rows you show have different `NAME` values, if the `ID` is a primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to union the results, so you have to concat each number with `UNION ALL` instead of comma , this [**should work**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c01bc/2/0):

```
SELECT Table1.* 
FROM dbo.Table1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT 120 UNION ALL SELECT 120)AS T(ID)
    ON Table1.ID = T.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine:

```
with DataToSelect(Id)
as
(
    select 1
    union all
    select 1
)
select
 TT.Id
from [dbo].[TestTable] TT
inner join DataToSelect DTS on DTS.Id = TT.Id
```

So instead of using `IN`, you have to build the options up there in the `with` clause. Of course, this is very tricky - you can't use parameters to pass the values, so this is vulnerable to exploits. Also, it will probably be relatively slow.

Instead, you might want to pass the possible values using a table parameter, where you can simply do something like this:

```
select
 TT.Id
from [dbo].[TestTable] TT
inner join @TableParam DTS on DTS.Id = TT.Id
```

Comment: This won't make it return different names though as it will just duplicate the same record.

Comment: @Szymon "When I give same id two times in a single selection I need two rows of same data but I can't get them" seems to indicate that's exactly what he wants.

Comment: Ok, maybe that's right...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably after union statement:

```
SELECT * FROM DRAWING WHERE ID = 120
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM DRAWING WHERE ID = 120
```

Answer (score -1):

ID is a primary and identity key, It won't allow a column with same value of ID. However if the two rows inserted anyhow, you will get result by SELECT * FROM DRAWING WHERE ID = 120

Comment: The 2 sentences of this answer contradict each other.

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking - he wants to return the same row twice, not two different rows with the same ID.

Comment: If he is not asking this then how would the columns value differ?

Comment: There are possibilities of redundant data in  rare conditions but this has not mentioned in the question.

Comment: i get those two same id values from differnt selection for cumulative pupose.the cumulative value needs two times of the same row.for that purpose only i need multiple times of the same row.